# Phase diagram (attractor and repellor) of autonomous 2nd-order ODE system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have a 2nd-order autonomous non-linear ODE system:
$$
\ddot{Y}+2A\dot{Y}+Y=BX
$$
$$
\ddot{X}+C\dot{X}+DX^2\dot{X}+EX=F\ddot{Y}+G\dot{Y}
$$
It includes two unknowns: Y(t) and X(t). And (A,B,C,D,E,F,G) are constants. The physics of this ode system is the oscillation of body Y(t) and the oscillation of fluid X(t). I use matlab function ode45() to numerically solve this system. Theoretically speaking, the initial conditions (IC) should be [Y(0),Y'(0),X(0),X'(0)] and I use 8 different ICs like [Y(0),0,0,0], Y(O)=0.0001-1.

I have a look at the dynamical system theory, and I think there are should be attractor or repellor in the phase space, so I plot the phase diagram of Y-Y', X-X' and X-Y for different ICs ([phase diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6j41M.png)). It seems that different ICS would converge to a limit cycle, does that mean all these ICs lie in the same basic of attraction of this attractor? And is there a repellor in the phase diagram? Sorry to ask such stupid question, I don't know more about chaotic theory. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Moo, I just plot unkown (X and Y) as x-axis and its first directive (X' and Y') as y-axis to get this phase diagram. X,X',Y,Y' can be obtained from numerical solution.

Comment: Maybe include some information about the constants of your equations, like are they all positive or are they within certain rages. These constants can have a profound effect on the dynamics of the system. Maybe even tell us what are the constants you have used to test your system and plot these phase diagrams.